# extract rate as a percent from access log file

Tags: php, awk, metrics

I am trying to calculate the Error rate % from a PHP application for PHP metrics. I read the access.log file and got help outputting the total HTTP 200, 300, 400, 500 errors but I want to graph the error rate based on the 400 and 500 errors:

awk '{print $9}' access.log | sort | uniq -c | sort -rn | awk '{total += $1; print} END {print total, "Total"}'

above gives me break down count and total of all HTTP errors. Obviously, 200 is not an error. To get the error rate, I would have to divide total / 400+500 error count. Whats the best way to search for 400 and 500 errors and divide by the total to get % rate..

Comment: Could you please post sample of input and expected output(in your question) for better understanding of your question.

Comment: ... and format the code (and input/output when  you add it) properly, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting?

Comment: I'm running this from the command line. Sample input:171.20.3.189 - - [06/Dec/2020:15:11:27 +0000] "GET /check.php HTTP/1.1" 200 33 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0" 171.20.3.189 - - [06/Dec/2020:15:54:06 +0000] "GET /Autodiscover/Autodiscover.xml HTTP/1.1" 404 209 "http://<IP address>:80/Autodiscover/Autodiscover.xml" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.108 Safari/537.36" My output should be the calculated rate such as 5 or 10, 19 etc... Plan is to run this every 5 minutes and push it to AWS cloudwatch.

Comment: Please, do not post sample data or the expected output as a comment or image, post it as a testable sample included in your original post. As you were instructed with the code, format the data properly also. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
awk '{ tot[$9]+=1 } END { for (i in tot) { totl+=tot[i]} print ((tot[500]+tot[400])/totl)*100"%" }' access.log
```

Create an array tot with the error code as the index and increment the counter every time the error is encountered. At the end, loop through the tot array an add to a running total (totl). Use this totl figure and the array figures for error 400 and 500 to perform the math required.